# Generate random numpy array from a given list of elements with at least one repetition of each element

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, random

I want to create an array (say `output_list`) from a given numpy (say `input_list`) after resampling such that each element from `input_list` exists in `output_list` at least once. The length of `output_list` will be always > the length of `input_list.`

I tried a few approaches, and I am looking for a faster method. Unfortunately, `numpy`'s `random.choice` doesn't guarantee that at least one element exists.

**Step 1: Generate Data**

```
import string
import random
import numpy as np

size = 150000
chars = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
input_list= [
            "".join(
                [random.choice(chars) for i in range(5)]
            ) for j in range(dict_data[1]['unique_len'])]
```

**Option 1:** 
Let's try `numpy`'s `random.choice` with uniform distribution in terms of probability.

```
output_list = np.random.choice(
    input_list,
    size=output_size,
    replace=True,
    p=[1/input_list.__len__()]*input_list.__len__()
    )
assert set(input_list).__len__()==set(output_list).__len__(),\
    "Output list has fewer elements than input list"
```

This raises assertion:

> Output list has fewer elements than input list

**Option 2**
Let's pad random numbers to `input_list` and then shuffle it.

```
output_list = np.concatenate((np.array(input_list),np.random.choice(
    input_list,
    size=output_size-input_list.__len__(),
    replace=True,
    p=[1/input_list.__len__()]*input_list.__len__()
)),axis=None)

np.random.shuffle(output_list)
assert set(input_list).__len__()==set(output_list).__len__(),\
    "Output list has fewer elements than input list"
```

While this doesn't raise any assertion, I am looking for a faster solution than this either algorithmically or using `numpy`'s in-built function.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `np.random.choice` assumes uniform probability, no need to set it explicitly, option 2 looks good to me, did you time it? is it really that slow?

Comment: Thanks filippo. The issue is that even if I time it, I won't know whether there is anything better solution. So, the answer to your question is that if there any other algorithm or function faster than above, then I can compare. 'np''s uniform distribution isn't really giving a uniform distribution, it seems. I have tried `output_size`>>>`input_size`.

Comment: `input_list.__len__()` is almost never preferable to `len(input_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Let `lenI` is input list length, `lenO` is output list length.

1) Make `lenO - lenI` iterations of uniform random choice from source list

2) Then append all input list in the end of output list

3) Then make `lenI` iterations of Fisher–Yates shuffle to distribute last elements uniformly.

```
import random
src = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lD = 10
lS = len(src)
dst = []
for _ in range(lD - lS):
    dst.append(src[random.randint(0, lS-1)])
dst.extend(src)
print(dst)
for i in range(lD - 1, lD - lS - 1, -1):
    r = random.randint(0, lD - 1)
    dst[r], dst[i] = dst[i], dst[r]
print(dst)

>>[4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>[4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

This is approach with linear complexity.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add timing and comparison with my assert statement. I am sorry, but I didn't follow your logic. It seems your suggestion is same as mine..i.e. append input list and randomize the remaining elements.

Comment: I am not strong enough in numpy to make reliable test. Plain Python example added. Seems your second approach is close to mine, but you don't need to shuffle all the list.